# The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a Windows service which does a **Bulk copy** to **Oracle 10g** server. This service  is working well in my machine. But when i instll this Service on another machine(which has got Oralcle 10g & VS 2010 installed) its giving below error.

**The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy' threw an exception.**

I have used **Oracle.DataAccess.dll** (version 2.112.3.0) which i have placed in my Service Bin folder.

Comment: Where is it giving that error?  There should be an inner exception that exposes more information; you'd need to find that in order to work out what's going on.

Comment: This happens when creating a new OracleBulkCopy() object. I have mentioned the InnerException below:The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration file. When oracle creates custom types in your VS2010 project, some properties are hard-coded in the configuration file (look for YourApplication.exe.config)

You'll find a <oracle.dataaccess.client> section. Check that  [schema owner] and [factory name] are correct for your "production" environment in all the custom types defined.

Comment: This happens when creating a new OracleBulkCopy() object. I have mentioned the InnerException below:The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client